# Find all emails in outlook inbox which are "undelivered" with powershell

Tags: scripting, outlook, powershell

I need to query my inbox with powershell recursivly for all "undelivered email returner"...

I have problems with the recursive part...

This is the script I ran:

```
$outlook = new-object -com Outlook.Application
$ns = $olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
$mb = $namespace.Folders | ?{$_.name -match "mailbox"}   
$folder1 = $mb.Folders | ?{$_.name -match "folder1"}   
$folder1.Folders | %{$_.name}  

$folder1.items | foreach {
if($_.subject -match "undelivered") {...}
}
```

However, this doesn't recursively list all the items.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a short script that should help you out.  It walks through all folders in a mailbox and outputs their path.  You can update the work done in the recursive section to check the items in each folder as it passes through them.

```
$outlook = New-Object -Com Outlook.Application
$mapi = $outlook.GetNamespace('MAPI')
$mailboxRoot = $mapi.GetDefaultFolder([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders]::olFolderInbox).Parent
$walkFolderScriptBlock = {
    param(
        $currentFolder
    )
    foreach ($item in $currentFolder.Folders) {
        $item.FolderPath
        & $walkFolderScriptBlock $item
    }
}
& $walkFolderScriptBlock $mailboxRoot
```